# Rename all files and folders in folder and sub folder

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I need to rename a whole file structure, and find a certain piece of string such as "_foo" and rename it to "". The structure will be like :
something_foo->multiples_folders_and_files_foo->multiples_folders_and_files_foo->files_foo

Where all the files in each folders and each folders in each folders must not contain the piece fo string "_foo".

I am working under windows. I have tried powershell script, I was able to rename a single folder, but not recursivly rename all folders.

thanks guys!

Comment: It would help if you showed us what code you have and we can help make it better. Right now it looks like you want us to create a whole solution for you which is not what SO is for.

Comment: Yep, I know this can be done in powershell with just 2 lines, we just need to see what you've done so we can help correct what you have not provide an entire solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "string_to_remove=_foo"
set "root_dir=c:\root"

pushd "%root_dir%"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

    for  %%f in (*) do (
        set "file_name=%%f"
        ren "!file_name!" "!file_name:%string_to_remove%=!"

    )


for /r /d %%# in (*) do ( 
    set "dir_name=%%#"
    pushd "%%#"
    for  %%f in (*) do (
        set "file_name=%%f"
        ren "!file_name!" "!file_name:%string_to_remove%=!"

    )
    popd 
    if "!dir_name!" NEQ "!dir_name:%string_to_remove%=!" move  "!dir_name!" "!dir_name:%string_to_remove%=!"
)
popd
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but try this (in PowerShell)

```
PS> ls -rec -path $path |  Ren -new { $_.name -replace '_foo' } -passthru
```

If work remove -`passthru` switch

Edit:
 If '_foo' in the end of the name you can change the expression like:

```
|  Ren -new { $_.basename -replace '_foo$' } -ea silentlycontinue
```

Edit:

For more robust code: (thank TheMadTechnician)

```
PS> GCI $path -filter '*_foo*' -rec |  Ren -new { $_.name -replace '_foo' } -passthru
```

Comment: That will spit back a lot of errors if he has anything without _foo in the name. You should have put in a `|Where{$_.Name -match "_foo"}|` in there.

Comment: Or setting "erroraction" with "silentlycontinue" value...because "where" Cmdlet is slow

Comment: Then he'd miss when files/folders can't be renamed due to ReadOnly or File In Use issues. If you feel that Where is too slow then filter at the provider level and do a `GCI $Path -Recurse -Filter "*_foo*" | Ren`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, +1 for the '-filter' param

Comment: Tried it, works great, but for some reason, at each execution, it only removes the "_foo" on one level ie.: folder_foo/folder_foo/file_foo, only the first folder_foo is removed, and if I re-execute, the second folder_foo will be renamed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "remove=_foo"

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "*%remove%*.*" 2^>nul ^| sort /r') do (
        set "name=%%~nxa"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%b in ("!name:%remove%=!") do endlocal & echo ren "%%~fa" "%%~b"
    )
```

This will enumerate all matching files/folders, sort in reverse order (so files are processed before the folders that contains them) and for each one, remove the indicated string

Rename operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command